# Are these load bearing walls?

Tags: walls, load-bearing

We are going to be remodeling our home and there are several walls I want to remove. All of the ones in the blue rectangle [image]le on the attached document. Is there a way to tell from the blueprint if they are load bearing?

Comment: Hard to tell with a small section of the house.  The only wall that looks close to being load bearing is in the yellow section of the plan.  Most load bearing wall/s tend to run down the middle of a house in a straight line.

Comment: The easiest way to tell if a wall is load-bearing is to look at all the things above it.  you're not making it easy.

Comment: There's not enough information in that drawing for anyone to tell you with any degree of certainty which, if any, of those walls are structural or load-bearing. If would help to know what's above that space. If you tear all the drywall off then looking at the structure of the walls themselves would help a lot, as would tearing the ceiling down ...